# Using node ActiveDirectory package, run getUsersForGroup() function NON-recursively

Tags: javascript, active-directory, backend

Using the [ActiveDirectory](https://github.com/gheeres/node-activedirectory) node package to query AD in a javascript backend.

I am able to get the `getUsersForGroup` function working, but function spec explicitly states:

> For the specified group, retrieve all of the users that belong to the group. If the group contains groups, then the members of those groups are recursively retrieved as well to build a complete list of users that belong to the specified group.

Is there any way to configure this to run NON-recursively? I want to organize the results by group, and the results don't show group membership so I'd have to retroactively determine it for each member...